# xsl Transformation for Grouping multi layer results

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping, xslkey

I am hoping that someone can help me asI have been trying to figure out how to make a transformation of a data set into a table structure that is grouped on multiple levels.  The first level is the Event Date, the second is the Company Name, and the last is the by the Users.

The following is the XML.

```
<xmlData>
    <records>
      <record>
        <userid>1</userid>
        <usersname>Jane Doe</usersname>
        <companyname>Company A</companyname>
        <eventdate>01 FEB 2017</eventdate>
        <jeventdate>2457786</jeventdate>
      </record>
      <record>
        <userid>3</userid>
        <usersname>Jane Doe</usersname>
        <companyname>Company B</companyname>
        <eventdate>01 FEB 2017</eventdate>
        <jeventdate>2457786</jeventdate>
      </record>
      <record>
        <userid>2</userid>
        <usersname>Joe Smith</usersname>
        <companyname>Company B</companyname>
        <eventdate>01 DEC 2016</eventdate>
        <jeventdate>2457724</jeventdate>
      </record>
      <record>
        <userid>2</userid>
        <usersname>Joe Smith</usersname>
        <companyname>Company B</companyname>
        <eventdate>01 JAN 2017</eventdate>
        <jeventdate>2457755</jeventdate>
      </record>
      <record>
        <userid>2</userid>
        <usersname>Joe Smith</usersname>
        <companyname>Company B</companyname>
        <eventdate>01 FEB 2017</eventdate>
        <jeventdate>2457786</jeventdate>
      </record>
    </records>
</xmlData>
```

The results that I am trying to get to is shown in the following simple HTML output.

```
<h1>01 DEC 2016</h1>
  <h2>Company B</h2>
  <table>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>Joe Smith</td></tr>
  </table>
<h1>01 JAN 2017</h1>
  <h2>Company B</h2>
  <table>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>Joe Smith</td></tr>
  </table>
<h1>01 FEB 2017</h1>
  <h2>Company A</h2>
  <table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>Jane Doe</td></tr>
  </table>
  <h2>Company B</h2>
  <table>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>Dave Dodd</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>Joe Smith</td></tr>
  </table>
```

The issue I am having is actually two parts.  The first is getting the three levels of depth.  The second is getting all the records and not just the first few.

Here is the XSL that I have been working with.

```
<xsl:key name="monthof" match="record" use="eventdate"/>
<xsl:key name="companyof" match="record" use="concat(eventdate,'|',companyname)"/>
<xsl:key name="userof" match="record" use="concat(eventdate,'|',companyname,'|',usersname)"/>

<xsl:template match="xmlData/records">
    <xsl:for-each select="record[key('monthof',eventdate)]">
        <xsl:sort select="jeventdate"/>
        <xsl:variable name="lstEventDate" select="key('monthof',eventdate)" />
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="eventdate"/></h2>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('companyof',concat(eventdate,'|',companyname))">
            <xsl:sort select="companyname"/>
            <h3>
                <xsl:value-of select="companyname"/>
            </h3>
            <table>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('userof',concat(eventdate,'|',companyname,'|',usersname))">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="userid"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="usersname"/></td>
                    </tr>                                   
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

And here is the output that I am getting.

```
01 DEC 2016

Company B

2 Jane Doe 

01 JAN 2017

Company B

2 Jane Doe 

01 FEB 2017

Company A

1 Joe Smith 

01 FEB 2017

Company B

1 Joe Smith 

Company B

3 Dave Dodd 

01 FEB 2017

Company B

1 Joe Smith 

Company B

2 Jane Doe
```

Comment: Start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html Then do a search for examples of multi-level Muenchian grouping here on SO.

Comment: For grouping problems you need to specify XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 because the answers will be quite different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys you have defined are fine but you need then to use them, as already pointed in a comment, with the [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) approach:

```
<xsl:template match="xmlData/records">
    <xsl:for-each select="record[generate-id() = generate-id(key('monthof',eventdate)[1])]">
        <xsl:sort select="jeventdate"/>
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="eventdate"/></h2>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('monthof', eventdate)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('companyof',concat(eventdate,'|',companyname))[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="companyname"/>
            <h3>
                <xsl:value-of select="companyname"/>
            </h3>
            <table>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('companyof',concat(eventdate,'|',companyname))[generate-id() = generate-id(key('userof',concat(eventdate,'|',companyname,'|',usersname))[1])]">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="userid"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="usersname"/></td>
                    </tr>                                   
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

You might want to check whether you can't move to XSLT 2.0 where it becomes a lot easier doing

```
<xsl:template match="xmlData/records">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="record" group-by="eventdate">
        <xsl:sort select="jeventdate"/>
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="eventdate"/></h2>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="companyname">
            <xsl:sort select="companyname"/>
            <h3>
                <xsl:value-of select="companyname"/>
            </h3>
            <table>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="usersname">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="userid"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="usersname"/></td>
                    </tr>                                   
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </table>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, this completely did what I was looking for.  It is the multi level application of the key that I just was not getting but now see it much more.  Wish I could do V2 but I am held ransom by Microsoft in Visual Studio and am not looking to make a change to another engine as the potential changes across the whole application would not warrant.